# nullPointerException at getWritableDatabase()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

New to Android here. I've made a new Fragments app, and I'm having trouble accessing the database from the Fragment.

Here's the class:

```
public class ShopListActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    DatabaseHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shoplist);

        db = new DatabaseHelper(this); // tried getApplicationContext(), and getBaseContext() as well

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }

    public void onClickAddProduct(View view) {
        TextView productName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.add_product_text);
        SQLiteDatabase dbWritable = db.getWritableDatabase(); // <-- crashes here

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("Name", (String) productName.getText());

        dbWritable.insert("Lists", "Name", values);
    }
```

All the other solutions I found on SO didn't help.
DatabaseHelper is a very basic DB Helper class:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLES);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Lists (Name) VALUES('Test')");
}
```

Here's the Logcat:

```
07-07 21:03:24.351    9641-9641/com.chas.shopforme             E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3606)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17362)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3601)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at com.chas.shopforme.ShopListActivity.onClickAddProduct(ShopListActivity.java:69)
        ... 14 more
```

**Note:** I know there are more questions like this, but their solutions didn't work for me.

Comment: As per android source code here (https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java),  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224) - Line 224 is accessing context, and it is null for your app to crash.  I am not able to think what is making the context in DbHelper become null.

Comment: Looks like the fragment hasn't yet been fully attached to an activity, so there may be issues with using "this". A couple of things to try: a) move the helper init to onResume, and close it in onPause. b) use a message handler to delay db helper creation via post. b is a bit of a hack.

Comment: b. is waayyyy beyond my understanding. Talk to me like a n00b :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Some sort of progress; crashes on same spot but with a `InvocationTargetException`

Comment: Solved it - that Exception was because I was casting `(String) productName.getText()` instead of `productName.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding this as a comment to your question, but nasty things happen to code in comments.

Assuming you've tried a) in the comment above, and it didn't work, an example of b) follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

    Handler hand = new Handler();
    hand.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dbInit();
        }
    });
}

public void dbInit() {
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
}
```

This allows the fragment manager to finish setting up the fragment before you try to use it. What it is doing is sending a message to itself which is processed when the fragment's message handler loop is running.

Comment: Well, I get an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` exception... So I assume solving that would let me use a more straightforward solution like @soynerdito's

Comment: I got the solution, the Invocation error lead me to another syntax problem; and like I said - the simpler solution by the other answer was better for me since I didn't wanna make it too complex. Still, thanks!